# Visual Studio Team Service fails Task Docker Build

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-build-task

I'm trying to run build Docker task to create a docker image. I set up a docker host, I'm using defautl Docker Hub as registry and my whole environment is on Azure.

When I queue a build task it fails at Task Docker.

Log output:

> check path : null
> task result: Failed
>
> Not found docker: null
>
> Finishing task: Docker
>
> [error]Task Docker failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.

Does someone have any thought on what may be happening?

Comment: What's the task definition? How did you queue it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After looking into this, it would seem this happens if Docker is not properly installed on the build agent for the service principal the agent is running under.

Keep in mind that:

- The Build **must** be run in a private agent, as the hosted ones do not yet have Docker installed, as per a very small footnote in the bottom of the [documentation](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker).
- The VSTS agent must be running with a principal that has the environment variables set for docker to run; the default is LocalService account, which won't have that installed. This turns out to be a problem with other stuff as well and I've found it best to have a special user principal to run the agent under, that can also log into the system.

Fixing these two issues made it work for me.

Comment: It took me a while to test, but following these make docker run perfectly on the agent. Thanks.

Comment: Great to hear that! Hopefully the team will improve the docs soon.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to switch the agent to Hosted VS2017 which has Docker support.

Comment: Could you please provide a brief info on how did you manage to setup the docker build with "Hosted VS2017"? It has docker support but I'm still getting errors during the build (linux-based container).

Comment: @PavelSapehin It's been a while and our scripts have changed since then. If I remember right I didn't do anything special and just switched to that agent. Ours already had Docker installed on that agent.

Comment: @PavelSapehin I just checked our latest build script, it ran fine on the Hosted Linux Preview, Hosted VS2017, and our private Linux. If failed on the Hosted agent because that one is missing .net core.

Comment: @QUAZZY If I'm not mistaken, the default "Hosted VS2017" is configured to run **Windows Docker Containers**. That is why the build ran unsuccessful for me. Also, I've tried to switch to "Hosted Linux Preview" (with **preinstalled** dotnetcore) but it hadn't have a docker support. Fortunately,I was able to install docker using "Bash Command" task via apt-get and the build passed (before building docker image, I'am also using "dotnet publish" task). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If Linux is an option, try Hosted Linux Preview